# How can I work on the output of jsonp in phonegap?

Tags: php, javascript, android, cordova

I am working on a PhoneGap with Android project. I have designed a login page in which I want to show an alert box for a valid and invalid user.  I am using PHP for database validation.

This is my php page:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "mymusic";

    $con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database, $con);
     $id=$_GET["id"];
     $pass=$_GET["password"];
    //$id='ram';
    //$pass='ram';
    $sql = "SELECT id, name,password FROM login where userid='$id' and password='$pass'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

    $records = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $records[] = $row;
    }

    mysql_close($con);

    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
    ?>
```

This is my java script function:

```
 function onDeviceReady(){
        var output = $('#output');
        var id = document.getElementById('userid').value;
        var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
       // webcam.set_api_url( 'test.php?filename=' + escape(filename));

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.1.214/sample/dologin.php?id='+id+'&password='+pass,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data, status){
                console.log('entered success============');
                $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

                var logi=item.id;
                if(logi!=null)
                    alert("valid user");
                else
                    alert("invalid user");

                });

            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('entered success====================');
               output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
            }
        });
 }
```

This is not working properly for an invalid user.  Whenever I enter a valid user name and password then it displays the valid user message box.  When I enter an invalid user name and password then it doesn't display anything.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Just a comment - you shouldn't be passing password as a query string parameter, because you reveal passwords to anyone who want to sniff them. These entries are also stored in web server log files. POST the password if you want to pass password to serverside.

Comment: yeah janis sir i want to pass password to server. thanks for your reply. please suggest me that what condition should i apply to make alert box related to valid and invalid user ..?

Comment: @Kuntal, well at the server side you check if for such user such a password is correct and then it's your choice in how do you wrap that data - after all you can send to client whatever you want and in javascript you can access that data.

Comment: actually sir i dont know the exact way for this. please help me...by giving example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try debugging this in a browser and perhaps send the returned jsonp data to the console from within your ajax's success call `console.log(data)`.

It's quite possible that your jsonp is returning some data as opposed to null... even if it is simply `undefined` or an empty string. Your conditional is most likely the culprit.

Comment: thank you sir...  i have done it using console.log(data). this is